# How to replace image in onfling method in gesture detector in android

Tags: android, android-gesture

I am trying to replace image in onFling Mehtod for swipe in gesture detector in android .It is not changing can anybody tell How to replace image in onfling method in gesture detector in android
Below is my code

```
 public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

                try {
                    if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)


                        return false;
                    // right to left swipe
                    if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

                        View view; 
                        View child;
                        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
                        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_help, null);

                        ImageView helpImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.helpImage);
                        helpImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.an_nav_screen);





                        Toast.makeText(context, "Left Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                        System.out.println("left swipe");
                    }  else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                        System.out.println("right swipe");

                        Toast.makeText(context, "Right Swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // nothing
                }
                return true;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
@Override

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if(e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            return fasle;
        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.generic_help, null);

            ImageView helpImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.helpImage);
            helpImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.an_nav_screen);

            return true;
        }
        if(e1.getY() - e2.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

            return false;
        } else if (e2.getY() - e1.getY() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {

            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

this may help you

Comment: nothing is changing in imageview onfling method is in separate class am passing context in onFling method